# Phonegap CordovaLib Semantic error

Tags: ios, cordova, mobile, ios4

I am using Phonegap 2.4.0 for iOS. when i create a cordova project and run it in iPad5.1 simulator i got this error

> semantic issue expected method to read dictionary element not found on
>   object of type 'Nsdictionary *'

i following this tutorial   [guide_getting-started_ios](http://docs.phonegap.com/en/2.4.0/guide_getting-started_ios_index.md.html#Getting%20Started%20with%20iOS)

and i don't know where i made mistake.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check your xcode version - it needs to be 4.5 or above.
Rebuild your cordova / phonegap project after upgrading xcode and the error should go away.

Answer (score 0):

If you have an updated version of Xcode, make sure your project/platforms/ios/build directory wasn't removed somehow.